# R: Confusion matrix indicates Classification method 1 is best, ROC indicates method 2

Tags: r, roc, auc

I may have confused myself doing these calculations, so I would really appreciate the feedback from a fresh set of eyes.

I have a 1/0 outcome (let's just call it faulty units in accordance with a guide I read on the subject).

27 units are faulty and 76 units are working correctly.

Method 1
Gives a 1/0 prediction and correctly identifies 4 units as defect and predicts that all other units are working.

Method 2
Gives a percentual estimation. On average it scores working units as 0.5 and faulty units as 0.3.

If I plot the ROC and compare AUC, it seems that Method 2 is clearly superior:
[image]

But when I call a confusion matrix, it seems that Method one is much better than what the plot indicated:

```
               Accuracy : 0.7767         
                 95% CI : (0.684, 0.8529)
    No Information Rate : 0.9612         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1              

                  Kappa : 0.2042         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 4.49e-06       

            Sensitivity : 1.00000        
            Specificity : 0.76768
```

Whereas a confusion matrix set for the threshold of 0.35 (middle of the two averages) makes method 2 appear relatively poor

```
               Accuracy : 0.699           
                 95% CI : (0.6008, 0.7855)
    No Information Rate : 0.6699          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.3033          

                  Kappa : 0.282           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.2812          

            Sensitivity : 0.4412          
            Specificity : 0.8261
```

I am a bit uncertain on which method to recommend and whether I am doing something wrong in the above comparisons? Code to reproduce is available [here](https://pastebin.com/mnr3JFAw).

Thanks for reading through my post and all feedback is more than appreciated.

Comment: Any method at the default threshold of 0.5 is rarely optimal. Just choose a better decision threshold for method 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still not sure that I understand, though. Method1 has a simple 1/0 output that I cannot manipulate. Is it in that case not optimal to create an ROC in the first place?

I could, of course, try to find a better threshold for Method 2, but how would I go about that in a way that should be better for future samples rather than the one I already have analysed?

Comment: The fact you cannot change the threshold of method 1 doesn't mean there isn't some thresholding going on behind the scenes. Find an alternative function that gives you the quantitative scores of method 1, or often just change one parameter to get those scores. Without any code from you it's hard to help and answer. You will see AUC increase as curves like method 1 systematically underestimate the AUC.